# How to get Base64 Encoded Image content with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I would like to get an image xpath, but this image encoded, is any way to get a content? this encoded image file have details like this:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>

data:image/png;base64,iVB.....
```

Comment: There is no XML in your question. How do you expect to use XPath on this input?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but if you have access to an XPath processor that implements the EXPath Binary Module (http://expath.org/spec/binary) then it should be possible.

Comment: I would like to get scrape from a special website, I got XPath code but within it, I saw image decoded and after that, I asked this question here

Comment: Its function like [`bin:encode-string`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/expath-binary/encode-string.html) Requires Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE. Unfortunately no Saxon-HE.